# Query to find rows with repeating characters in a column

Tags: sql, sql-server

My DB is SQL server 2019. I had a phone number column in my table and i've to find invalid phone numbers entered by the end users. One such bad data is 9999999999. Currently i'm querying like this to identify such values.

`SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE PHN_NUM IN ('999999999','111111111','22222222','333333333')`

Can some one help with a logical query to find this without mentioning all these bad data ?

Comment: Please define what "bad data" looks like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove phone numbers where all the characters are the same, then one approach is `replace()`:

```
where replace(PHN_NUM, left(PHN_NUM, 1), '') = ''
```

That is, replace the first character to see.  If none are left, then all characters are the same.

Answer (score 0):

I created a function a couple days ago that handle this type of thing quite nicely.
Using [ngrams8k](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/nasty-fast-n-grams-part-1-character-level-unigrams) I created a function called SequenceIsland (yeah, needs a better name)... It works like this:

```
DECLARE @string VARCHAR(1000) = 'blah.. 111111111... 222222222... 33333333333...';
SELECT  sg.ItemIndex, sg.ItemLen, sg.Item
FROM    dbo.SequenceIsland8k(@string) AS sg
```

**Results:**

```
ItemIndex  ItemLen  Item
---------- -------- ----------------
1          1        b
2          1        l
3          1        a
4          1        h
5          2        ..
7          1         
8          9        111111111
17         3        ...
20         1         
21         9        222222222
30         3        ...
33         1         
34         11       33333333333
45         3        ...
```

It tokenizes a string by values repeated 0 or more times, what I call a ***Sequence Island***. The function returns the "island", position in the string and it's length. Now you can filter by length by adding: `WHERE   sg.ItemLen > 3` revealing that there are three candidates - at position 8, 31 and 34

```
ItemIndex   ItemLen   Item
----------- --------- ------------
8           9         111111111
21          9         222222222
34          11        33333333333
```

You can do other things with it too, such as remove or mask data; e.g.

```
DECLARE @string VARCHAR(1000) = 'blah.. 111111111... 222222222... 33333333333...';

SELECT  NewString = STRING_AGG(IIF(sg.ItemLen > 3 AND sg.token LIKE '[0-9]',
                              '<SomeNumber>',sg.Item),'') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY sg.ItemIndex)
FROM    samd.SequenceIsland8k(@string) AS sg;
```

**Returns:**

```
blah.. <SomeNumber>... <SomeNumber>... <SomeNumber>...
```

**The Function:**

```
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION dbo.SequenceIsland8k -- AKA SEQUENCE GRAMS (S-Grams)
(
  @string  VARCHAR(8000)
)
RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING AS RETURN
SELECT 
  Token        = ng.Token,
  ItemNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ng.Position),
  ItemIndex  = ng.Position,
  ItemLen    = i.Ln,
  Item       = item.Txt
FROM (
  SELECT
    ng.Position, ng.Token, IIF(LAG(ng.Token,1) OVER (ORDER BY ng.Position) = ng.Token,0,1)
  FROM   dbo.ngrams8k(@string,1) AS ng)                  AS ng(Position,Token,ngMatch)
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(SUBSTRING(@string,ng.Position,8000))) AS s(St) -- This Suffix
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(PATINDEX('%[^'+ng.Token+']%',s.St)))  AS nxt(C)
CROSS APPLY (VALUES((LEN(@string)+2)-ng.Position))        AS final(Ln)
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(ISNULL(NULLIF(nxt.C,0),final.Ln)-1))  AS i(Ln) -- Item Len
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(SUBSTRING(@string,ng.Position,i.Ln))) AS item(Txt)
WHERE       ng.ngMatch = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Another option is to search the string for any characters which don't match the first:**

```
WHERE YourString NOT LIKE '%[^' + REPLACE(LEFT(YourString, 1), '\', '\\') + ']%' ESCAPE '\'
```